# Saveas Filename with future date

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am trying to save my workbook with a date that is 28 days from today. Here's my code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
     strDate = CDate(Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy"))
     strNewDate = DateAdd("D", 28, strDate)
     strFileName = Format("SCNI_Exceptions_") & strNewDate
     .SaveAs strFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End With
```

I am getting error 'Method 'SaveAs' of Object '_Workbook' failed. Any help and explanation of the solution is appreciated.

Thanks 
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strNewDate = DateAdd("D", 28, strDate)` produces a date with `/` delimiters which you use a part of the file name and which would point to a non-existent directory.

Instead;

```
strNewDate = Format$(DateAdd("D", 28, Now), "dd-mm-yyyy")
strFileName = "SCNI_Exceptions_" & strNewDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `strNewDate` is in the format dd/mm/yyyy and you can't have '/' characters in a filename.

Try using something like `strNewDate = Format(DateAdd("D", 28, Now()), "yyyyMMdd")`